# Add variable to android manifests file

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-manifest

Is it possible to add a variable to manifests.xml file ?

For example, I'm setting FCM for my app and there's a piece of code:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

My app need the `@string/default_notification_channel_id` changeable, is there any particalar way to do that ?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use manifest placeholder for that, Using It you will be able to have these based on app flavours

In your **build.gradle** file.

```
debug {
  minifyEnabled false
  debuggable true
  applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
  manifestPlaceholders = ["default_notification_channel_id": "abcdefgh"]
}
release {
  minifyEnabled true
  debuggable false

  manifestPlaceholders = ["default_notification_channel_id": "xyzuvw"]
}
```

and In your **AndroidManifest** file

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
  android:value="${default_notification_channel_id}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but Is this the only way ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes